# Python - Как принять аргумент в функции с именем 'from'

Tags: python, fastapi

Использую FastAPI. Функция - обработчик в качестве аргументов принимает имена Query параметров из запроса.
Вот сама функция обработчик:

```
@api.get('/visited_links/')
def upload_links(from: str):
    from_time = from
    print(from_time)
```

Такой подход понятно, что работать не будет. 
Пробовал вот так:

```
@api.get('/visited_links/')
def upload_links(*args, **kwargs):
    from_time = kwargs.get('from')
    print(from_time)
```

Но на такой подход ругается FastAPI и не хочет передавать параметры в такую функцию.
Обращаться к API по другому не вариант.
Переезжать на DRF ради такой мелочи нет желания.
Спасибо!

Comment: Странно. В функции переменные можно именовать как хочешь. Для ее вызывателей по идеи важна только позиция этого аргумента. Вы пробовали переименовать в _from?

Comment: Скорее даже не отказывается передавать, а ждет параметр 'kwargs' в качестве query параметра.

Comment: А вы хотите получить параметры запроса? Типа: `/visited_links/?from=999`?

Answer (score 3):

Можно в функцию добавить параметр [Request](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/), что описывает запрос, а из него получить параметры:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
def read_item(item_id: int, request: Request):
    query_params = request.query_params

    print(query_params['from'])
    # 9999

    return {"item_id": item_id, "q": query_params}
```

При открытии http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/5?q=somequery&from=9999 вернуло:

```
{"item_id":5,"q":{"q":"somequery","from":"9999"}}
```

---

**PS.**

[Описание типа Request](https://www.starlette.io/requests/)

Comment: Спасибо за хорошее решение!

Answer (score 3):

Вариант @gil9red работает, все отлично.
Однако хотелось бы не терять в авто-документации. 
Решил вопрос с помощью Query и alias, если вдруг кому-то пригодится.

```
@api.get('/visited_links/')
def get_links(to: str, q: str = Query(None, alias="from")):
    try:
        filtered_domains = store.filter_domains_by_time(time_from=q, time_to=to)
        return Response(details={'domains': filtered_domains}).json()
    except Exception as e:
        return Response(status=str(e)).json()
```

**P.S.**
[Ссылка на документацию о Query](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/)